# Winedt 7.0 + MiKTeX 2.9 compile Problem

Tags: bibtex, biber

I keep getting the following error and have no idea what to do! Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
Command Line:   `bibtex.exe "PA1_A2"`

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit);

The top-level auxiliary file: PA1_A2.aux I found no \citation
commands---while reading file PA1_A2.aux

I found no \bibdata command---while reading file PA1_A2.aux

I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file PA1_A2.aux (There
were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. Which version of `biblatex` do you use? Do you use `bibtex` or `biber`?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It could be a editor problem or a problem with your `tex` code. Please include a small `bib` file with package `filecontents` in your MWE.

Comment: I don't know, how do I find out?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have a bibliography that has to be compiled with `biber` and you are trying to compile it with `bibtex`.

Also you are probably using `PDFTeXify` command in WinEdt and this compiles with `bibtex` if you don't specify that you want to use `biber`. To do that in WinEdt, go to `Options` -> `Execution modes` -> `Console Applications` -> `Accessories` -> `BibTeX` and change `Executable` definition from `bibtex.exe` to `biber.exe`.

Otherwise you can download a contribution of mine: [LaTeXify](http://www.winedt.org/Config/menus/LaTeXify.php) which adds several commands to the `TeX` menu suitable for automated compilations

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
%@article{gander2001,
% author={Gladstone Gander},
% title={How to be lucky},
% journal={Nature},
% pages={1-33},
% volume={42},
% year={2001},
%}
%@article{ducks2002,
% author={Donald Duck and Fethry Duck},
% title={How to be unlucky},
% journal={Nature},
% pages={34-44},
% volume={43},
% year={2002},
%}
%@book{scrooge1901,
% author={Scrooge McDuck},
% title={My first golden nugget in {Klondike}},
% publisher={Yukon Press},
% address={Whitehorse},
% year={1901},
%}
%@book{scrooge1990,
% author={Scrooge McDuck},
% title={How to manage zillion of dollars},
% publisher={McDuck Press},
% address={Duckburg},
% year={1990},
%}
%\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
You should use a \verb|\cite{bib key}| in your document%~\cite{scrooge1901}.
To print all the references in the bib file without citing them in the text, use
\verb|\nocite{*}|. %\nocite{*}

You should also specify a bibliography style and provide a .bib file as below.
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

If you run `pdflatex`  and then `bibtex` on this file, one will get this error message by `bibtex`:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: doi.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file doi.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file doi.aux
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Now uncomment all commented things:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{gander2001,
 author={Gladstone Gander},
 title={How to be lucky},
 journal={Nature},
 pages={1-33},
 volume={42},
 year={2001},
}
@article{ducks2002,
 author={Donald Duck and Fethry Duck},
 title={How to be unlucky},
 journal={Nature},
 pages={34-44},
 volume={43},
 year={2002},
}
@book{scrooge1901,
 author={Scrooge McDuck},
 title={My first golden nugget in {Klondike}},
 publisher={Yukon Press},
 address={Whitehorse},
 year={1901},
}
@book{scrooge1990,
 author={Scrooge McDuck},
 title={How to manage zillion of dollars},
 publisher={McDuck Press},
 address={Duckburg},
 year={1990},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
You should use a \verb|\cite{bib key}| in your document~\cite{scrooge1901}.
To print all the references in the bib file without citing them in the text, use
\verb|\nocite{*}|. \nocite{*}

You should also specify a bibliography style and provide a .bib file as below.
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Now run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex` and `pdflatex` in this sequence on this, no errors are generated.

**Moral**

1. You should have a `.bib` file in the same directory (here
   `\jobname.bib` generated by `filecontents`).
2. You should use a `\cite{bib key}` in the document.
3. You should specify a bibliography style.
4. You should include the bib file in the document via
       `\bibliography{\jobname}`.
5. For a more specific answer, you should provide a MWE!

Comment: Using `arara` probably will be easier.